# Toggle between Mdi Children

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI form in which I create two MDIChild forms, cf1 and cf2.
I have a button which, when clicked, should toggle the "focus" (i.e. which form is "on top") between cf1 and cf2.
In the constructor of the MDI parent, I assign the MDIParent of the respective cf1 and cf2. Then I execute cf1.Show() then cf2.Show(), thus cf2 ends up "on top" or "focused."
When I press the toggle button the first time, cf1 becomes focused and cf2 becomes inactive.
Any further attempts to change the z-order after this are unsuccessful.

I have tried Activate, ActivateMdiChild, TopMost and BringToFront, all without success.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MDITest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly ChildForm cf1 = new ChildForm();
        private readonly ChildForm cf2 = new ChildForm();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cf1.MdiParent = this;
            cf2.MdiParent = this;
            cf1.Text = "Window 1";
            cf2.Text = "Window 2";
            cf1.Show();
            cf2.Show();
        }

        private void Child_WMSize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblWindow1State.Text = $"Window 1 - {cf1.WindowState.ToString()}";
            LblWindow2State.Text = $"Window 2 = {cf2.WindowState.ToString()}";
        }

        private void BtnFocus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf1) cf2.Activate();
            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf2) cf1.Activate();

            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf1) ActivateMdiChild(cf2);
            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf2) ActivateMdiChild(cf1);

            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf1) cf2.TopMost = true;
            //if (ActiveMdiChild == cf2) cf1.TopMost = true;

            if (ActiveMdiChild == cf1) cf2.BringToFront();
            if (ActiveMdiChild == cf2) cf1.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result would be to toggle the focus between the two forms as needed. The actual result is that I can only change from cf2 to cf1, not the other way around.

I even tried the shotgun approach:

```
    if (ActiveMdiChild == cf1)
    {
        cf2.BringToFront();
        cf2.Activate();
        ActivateMdiChild(cf2);
        cf2.TopMost = true;
        cf1.TopMost = false;
    }
    if (ActiveMdiChild == cf2)
    {
        cf1.BringToFront();
        cf1.Activate();
        ActivateMdiChild(cf1);
        cf1.TopMost = true;
        cf2.TopMost = false;
    }
```

With no change in my results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to toggle between any number of Mdi children windows:

```
if (MdiChildren.Length == 0)
    return;
var i = Array.IndexOf(MdiChildren, ActiveMdiChild);
MdiChildren[(MdiChildren.Length + i + 1) % MdiChildren.Length].Activate();
```

Or

```
this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First()
    .SelectNextControl(ActiveMdiChild, true,true, true, true);
```

Or

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}"); // Control + TAB as well as Control + F6
```

[image]

Comment: Why yes, this does work - would you perhaps happen to know the reason why this approach works and mine does not? I mean, I debug through my code and see all of the variables change state to what I think they should. But once I exit the method, nothing appears to have happened.

Comment: I didn't debug the problem but `ActivateMdiChild` didn't work as expected for me.